# Tic Tac Toe checking winner in boolean method

Tags: java

I'm playing a TicTacToe game where the user plays the computer. The user is always X and the computer is O. I have my code written to check every row, column, and diagonal to see if the user or computer wins. If neither then it just prints false. I would like the game to print out if the user win Human player won" or if the computer wins "Computer won". I just don't know how to add it to the boolean method.

```
public static boolean checkWin()
{
    //checks for human win
    if ("X".equals(board[0][0]) && "X".equals(board[0][1]) && "X".equals(board[0][2]))
        return true;
    else if ("X".equals(board[1][0]) && "X".equals(board[1][1]) && "X".equals(board[1][2]))
        return true;
    else if ("X".equals(board[2][0]) && "X".equals(board[2][1]) && "X".equals(board[2][2]))
        return true;
    else if ("X".equals(board[0][0]) && "X".equals(board[1][0]) && "X".equals(board[2][0]))
        return true;
    else if ("X".equals(board[0][1]) && "X".equals(board[1][1]) && "X".equals(board[2][1]))
        return true;
    else if ("X".equals(board[0][2]) && "X".equals(board[1][2]) && "X".equals(board[2][2]))
        return true;
    else if ("X".equals(board[0][0]) && "X".equals(board[1][1]) && "X".equals(board[2][2]))
        return true;
    else if ("X".equals(board[0][2]) && "X".equals(board[1][1]) && "X".equals(board[2][0]))
        return true;
    //checks if computer has won
    else if ("O".equals(board[0][0]) && "O".equals(board[0][1]) && "O".equals(board[0][2]))
        return true;
    else if ("O".equals(board[1][0]) && "O".equals(board[1][1]) && "O".equals(board[1][2]))
        return true;
    else if ("O".equals(board[2][0]) && "O".equals(board[2][1]) && "O".equals(board[2][2]))
        return true;
    else if ("O".equals(board[0][0]) && "O".equals(board[1][0]) && "O".equals(board[2][0]))
        return true;
    else if ("O".equals(board[0][1]) && "O".equals(board[1][1]) && "O".equals(board[2][1]))
        return true;
    else if ("O".equals(board[0][2]) && "O".equals(board[1][2]) && "O".equals(board[2][2]))
        return true;
    else if ("O".equals(board[0][0]) && "O".equals(board[1][1]) && "O".equals(board[2][2]))
        return true;
    else if ("O".equals(board[0][2]) && "O".equals(board[1][1]) && "O".equals(board[2][0]))
        return true;
    else
        //it's a tie
        return false;
}
```

Comment: I suggest you write **another method** which first calls `checkWin()`. Then print out a message depending on the returned result. Don't modify `checkWin()` to print the message

Comment: While printing the human/computer won could be put in there, it would probably fit better in a different location.  Why are you trying to put it into that method specifically?  I recommend keeping methods as simple as possible, in this case keeping the `checkWin` method only checking wins

Comment: Also, there's a flaw in your logic - this seems to assume that the only possible board configurations are "someone won" and "it's a tie," which is definitely *not* true.

Comment: Another problem I see with this is: If anyone wins it says true and it only says false if there's a draw. Edit: typo and cudos to @EJoshuaS because same comment

Comment: Think about it: If you check if someone has won after a player put their symbol in a move, then obviously the winner is the one who has made that move.

Answer (score 1):

The general rule of thumb is that each method should do one thing and do it well. In this case, `checkWin()` does exactly what its name implies: it checks if the human or computer won. If you add code to print a message, then it should real then it should be called `checkWinAndPrintWinner()`. Now it is obvious that you are trying to do two things in the function. Instead, you should write another method named `printWinner()` which calls `checkWin()` and then prints the appropriate message.

Answer (score 1):

After the human's turn, call `checkWin`.  If it returns true, then print the "human won" message and end the game.

After the computer's turn, call `checkWin`.  If it returns true, then print the "computer won" message and end the game.

If nine moves have occurred and `checkWin` hasn't returned true, the game is a tie.

Answer (score 0):

Although I agree with other answers that say a method should do one thing, if you want to do it that way you can create a class, Result

```
public class Result{
    boolean win;
    String message;
}
```

and return Result instead of boolean

```
public static Result checkWin()
{
    Result result = new Result();
    if ("X".equals(board[0][0]) && "X".equals(board[0][1]) && "X".equals(board[0][2])){
        result.win = true;
        result.messsage = "Computer won";    
    }
    ...


    return result;

}
```